# Question about questions kind of that if $p(x-3)-(x+1)p(x)=2x+1$, what is $p(-7)$?

Tags: functions, polynomials

**Question about questions kind of that if $p(x-3)-(x+1)p(x)=2x+1$, what is $p(-7)$?**

Firstly: Put $x=-1$, then we have $p(-4)=-1$, then put $x=-4$ and get $p(-7)=-10$.

Secondly: Assume $p$ is a polynomial, then see there is no such polynomial.

(Actually, these questions starts with "Let $p$ be a polynomial.").

My question: How can we show there is a such **function** or not, **"in general"**?

Comment: For one, you need to know that $p(-1)$ exists and is finite.

Comment: Is it necessary? I want to show there is a function which has this relation property. Because, if there is a such "function", then $p(-7)$ has to be $-10$. $p(-1)$ is defined or not, it is not important. I hope I didn't misunderstand your comment.

Comment: Your reasining relies on $(x+1) p(x)$ at $x=-1$ being zero.  What if $p(x) = a/(x+1)$?

Comment: Actually, since the relation holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $p$ has to be defined for every $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Relationship $\forall x, p(x-3)-(x+1)p(x)=2x+1$ cannot hold for a constant $p(x)$ and cannot hold either for non-constant polynomial because in this case th degree on the LHS is at least 2, whereas it is one on the RHS.

Comment: @JeanMarie, yes. This is the second observation. My question is not for polynomials, it is for functions.